# Partition of a rectangle into smaller rectangles, with their diagonals forming a loop

Tags: geometry, rectangles

The Big and the Small Kingdom are both rectangular islands and divided into rectangular landscape. In each province there is a road that runs along one of the diagonals. On each island exist roads that make a closed route, which does not go through any point several times. The picture shows the Little Kingdom, which has six area:

[image]

The Great Kingdom has an odd number of landscapes. How many landscapes does the Great Kingdom have at least?

Comment: It's a tricky question, I've tried it and still working on it.

Comment: Does the closed route have to pass through all the regions?

Comment: Ok, then I found a solution with $7$ regions. With $3$ is clearly impossible, so remains the case $5$.

Comment: How, can you prove it?

Comment: Sorry, prove what?

Comment: That 7 is the least possible provinces.

Comment: The closed route has to pass through all regions, otherwise it is easy to find such closed loops

Comment: If the closed route need not go through all provinces, then 5 suffices

Comment: I confirm that there exists a solution whith $5$. Now I'll try to post a picture.

Comment: Even if it must pass through all provinces it is possible with 5. Consider a large rectangle with 2 equal squares adjacent to one other, resting on the side of the rectangle. With another two adjacent squares resting on the adjacent line (to the previous one) of the rectangle. It is then simple to connect the diagonals. Don't ask me to post a picture as that seems like a nightmare to do.

Comment: could you post a picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one requires the route go through all provinces, then $9$ suffices (as shown by diagram below).

$\hspace1in$ [image: A route on 9 provinces]

**Update**

In fact, $9$ is the smallest odd number that does the job. The basic arguments go like this:

1. Consider the "four" rectangles covering the four corners of kingdom. They must be distinct from each other. Otherwise, there will be a rectangle that cover an edge of kingdom. Independent of which diagonal one pick, one of the endpoints of the diagonal will be in a position impossible to extend.
2. Over each edge, there can be rectangles between the corner rectangles. e.g. in the left edge of above diagram, there are two rectangles (magenta and green) between the red rectangle at top and olive-green rectangle at bottom.
   The key is in order for the route to be possible to extend, the number of such filling rectangles on each edge need to be even.
3. This means the total number of rectangles on the edges $N$ is an even number $\ge 4$.
4. $N$ cannot be $4$, Otherwise, the four corner rectangles are next to each other. There is only one way to pick the diagonals but that will lead to
   a closed route which one cannot add more diagonals.
5. Next, let us consider the case $N = 6$ and look at the diagonals of magenta and green rectangles in above diagram for inspiration. One will discover no matter how one place the $6$ rectangles on the edge, there is only one legal way to pick the $6$ diagonals. After you pick the diagonals, the two dangling endpoints are either lying on a horizontal or a vertical line. This means we need at least $3$ more edges (i.e 9 edges) to construct a closed route of odd length.
6. Finally, if $N \ge 8$, we need at least one more edge to construct a closed route of odd length. Once again, this means we need at least $9$ edges to do the job.

Combine $5.$ and $6.$ and the diagram above, we can conclude $9$ is the smallest odd number that one can construct a closed route of odd length.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with $5$ regions :

[image]

Comment: This is not correct as you have missed one provinces.

Comment: OP said that condition was not required.

Comment: Well, I thought it wasn't necessary but it is since the proof was too obvious. I found that one as well, but I found it weird that it actually exist a solution since it seems impossible.

Comment: I think that with that condition the problem would be a lot more interesting.